# как вызвать сеттер класса деда, минуя сеттер отца (сеттер деда и сеттер отца одинаково называются, JS)?

Tags: javascript, полиморфизм, класс

Как вызвать сеттер класса деда, минуя сеттер отца (сеттер деда и сеттер отца одинаково называются, JS)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь пример кода с этими объектами, как они определены и какой результат ожидаешь.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Вынесите логику из сетера деда в отдельный метод и вызывайте этот метод там, где требуется.

Comment: а через super.__proto__ не получится?

Comment: @Aleksey, нет, потому что тогда добавится в прототип, а не в нужный объект. И если уже используешь super, то proto в принципе не нужен